# If $T : \mathbb R^{n} \longrightarrow \mathbb R^{m}$ be a linear operator then it is differentiable over $\mathbb R^{n}$.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, proof-verification

**My attempt** :

Let $T : \mathbb R^{n} \longrightarrow \mathbb R^{m}$ be a linear operator.Let $x \in \mathbb R^n$.Now consider the limit

$$\lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac {||T(x + h) - T(x) - T(h)||} {||h||}$$.

Since $T$ is linear the above limit can easily be proved to $0$.So by the uniqueness of total derivative or differential coefficient of $T$ at $x \in \mathbb R^{n}$ it follows that $T$ possesses differential coefficient at each point of $\mathbb R^{n}$ which is precisely $T$ itself.Hence $T$ is differentiable over $\mathbb R^{n}$.

Does this proof hold good.Please verify it.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Looks fine, but what do you mean by _differential coefficient_? Also you don't need the uniqueness? You just need to find a linear operator for every $x$ such that the limit vanishes. Your proof should end after "... proved to be $0$."

Comment: Yeh you are right.I just show that the differential coefficient (or total derivative) exists and it is precisely $T$ due to the uniqueness, not anything else.Actually it not only proves that $T$ is differentiable over $\mathbb R^{n}$ but also determines how does the differential coefficient of $T$ at any point $x \in \mathbb R^{n}$ look like.Whatever I proved my requirement.That's all.Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An idea using the characterisation of linear operators from linear algebra:

$$T:\,\Bbb R^n\to\Bbb R^m\;\;\text{is linear}\iff T(\vec x)=\begin{pmatrix}T_1\vec x\\\ddots\\T_m\vec x\end{pmatrix}\;,\;\;\text{with each and every}\;\;T_i$$

a linear functional = a homogeneous polynomial in $\;x_1,...,x_n\;$ of degree one.

Now then it is easy to see each coordinate function of $\;T\;$ is a differentiable function and thus so is $\;T\;$ , or if you prefer: all the partial derivatives of $\;T\;$ at any point exist and are continuous everywhere (in fact, it is enough to show all but one partial derivatives are continuous...), and thus $\;T\;$ is differentiable.